# WSO2 BPS: H2 DB size

Tags: wso2, h2, wso2-business-process

I have an WSO2 BPS environment, over default H2 database; since some days ago, my DB is growing without control, until be > 20 Gb. Is any way to avoid this behavior or some commands to compact or clean this file?.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To answer this question we will need more information. What details can you provide? Do you know what specifically is adding information to your database?

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute process cleanup task by configuring scheduler at bps.xml.
   [Documentation Link1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/Process+Instance+Cleanup): Process Instance clean Up
2. When executing BPS, lot of events are generated by default and hence database is size is increased. You can limit the event generation by configuring “Event filtering”. This can be done on “Process Level” and “Scope Level”
   [Documentation Link2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/Process+Instances): Refer Filtering Events

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation @shashika.
I will take your advice. However, right now my base jpadb.h2.db is still very large even after deleting instances. I tried it with commands such as Shutdown compact without success. There are some other action I can take to reduce their size?